# returning a var from JS in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am quite confused on how to extract the value of a var in a js executed in UIWebView, my code is:

```
NSString * js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"  
                     "script.type = 'text/javascript';"  
                     "script.text = \"function getTopLeftCorner() { "  
                        "var el = document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f);"
                        "var pos = [el.offsetLeft, el.offsetTop];"
                        "var parent = el.offsetParent;"
                        "if (parent != el) {" 
                            "while (parent) {"  
                             "pos[0] += parent.offsetLeft;" 
                             "pos[1] += parent.offsetTop;" 
                             "parent = parent.offsetParent;"
                            "}"
                        "}"
                        "return pos;"
                      "}\";"  
                      "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"
                     , pt.x, pt.y];  

    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    NSString * result = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getTopLeftCorner()"];

    NSLog(@"RESULT IS %@", result);
```

Any idea why the result is empty?

Comment: are you fetching the results after `webViewDidFinishLoad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first statement `NSString * js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var script` closes the string at the end of the line, then follows several more `C strings`. You should be getting a syntax error from the Objective-C compiler.

To concatenate strings use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", three, two, one];`. Read through the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) for a greater explanation of the method.